# add class to element when scroll into view

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want trying to add class to my elements while they scrolled into view.so far I have done [This Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4mqpdza4/). Its not working.

I have made it for up to down scroll. I want to it for down to up scroll too

```
scrollOffset = 200;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('.wpb_animate_when_almost_visible').each(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() - scrollOffset > $(this).position().top) {
      if ($(this).hasClass('wpb_start_animation')){
            $(this).toggleClass('wpb_start_animation');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

### Is this correct method?? or am I doing all wrong?

**Edit**

Check my new Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/gd4yj5pu/2/

Comment: use removeClass / addClass instead of toggleClass

Comment: @Jigar Tried Please chek my fiddle

Answer (score 2):

Add `transition: all 2s ease 0s;` in css and use condition `if ($(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height() >= $(this).position().top && $(window).scrollTop() < $(this).position().top + $(this).height())` in jquery to toggle the class.

**DEMO:-**

```js
scrollOffset = 200;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('.wpb_animate_when_almost_visible').each(function() {
      //console.log(this+$(this).position().top);
    if ($(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height() >= $(this).position().top && $(window).scrollTop() < $(this).position().top + $(this).height()) {
      //console.log(this+$(this).position().top);
      //if ($(this).hasClass('wpb_start_animation')){
      if (!$(this).hasClass('wpb_start_animation')){
      $(this).addClass('wpb_start_animation');
      }
    }
    else if ($(this).hasClass('wpb_start_animation')) {
      //console.log(this+$(this).position().top);
      //if ($(this).hasClass('wpb_start_animation')){
      $(this).removeClass('wpb_start_animation');
      //}
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.wpb_animate_when_almost_visible {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
     -webkit-transition: all 2s ease 0s;
     -moz-transition: all 2s ease 0s;
     -o-transition: all 2s ease 0s;
     -ms-transition: all 2s ease 0s;*/
     transition: all 2s ease 0s;
}
.wpb_start_animation {
  height: 200px;
  width: 900px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <div class="wpb_animate_when_almost_visible" data-scroll-to="100"></div>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <div class="wpb_animate_when_almost_visible" data-scroll-to="200"></div>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
</body>
```

### Update

> When you have a scrollable div inside the body then you have to listen
>   to the `$('.staticscroller')` scroll to animate it  when it comes
>   visible while scrolling. Use the following demo

**DEMO:-**

```js
scrollOffset = 200;

$('.staticscroller').scroll(function() {
  $('.wpb_animate_when_almost_visible').each(function() {
    //console.log(this+$(this).position().top);
    //var myPosit=$(this).offset().top - $(".staticscroller").offset().top;
    var myPosit = $(".staticscroller").scrollTop() + $(this).position().top - $(".staticscroller").height() / 2 + $(this).height() / 2;
    if ($('.staticscroller').scrollTop() + $('.staticscroller').height() >= myPosit && $('.staticscroller').scrollTop() < myPosit + $(this).height()) {
      //console.log(this+$(this).position().top);
      //if ($(this).hasClass('wpb_start_animation')){
      if (!$(this).hasClass('wpb_start_animation')) {
        $(this).addClass('wpb_start_animation');
      }
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('wpb_start_animation')) {
      //console.log(this+$(this).position().top);
      //if ($(this).hasClass('wpb_start_animation')){
      $(this).removeClass('wpb_start_animation');
      //}
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
div.staticscroller {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
.wpb_animate_when_almost_visible {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 2s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 2s ease 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 2s ease 0s;
  */ transition: all 2s ease 0s;
}
.wpb_start_animation {
  height: 200px;
  width: 900px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="staticscroller">
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
    
    <div>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <div class="wpb_animate_when_almost_visible" data-scroll-to="100"></div>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <div class="wpb_animate_when_almost_visible" data-scroll-to="200"></div>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
    </div>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>a</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This code not working as it needs to be.....scrolloffset giving me problem.....is there any way If it checks element is in view port automatically.... I am trying something else could you please review this code https://jsfiddle.net/gd4yj5pu/2/

Comment: reference http://jsfiddle.net/RJX5N/2/

Comment: could you explain in detail. why do u need a `scrolloffset` here? how u need exactly?

Comment: I dont need `scrolloffset` . Actually I need effect on scroll. In your answer, code is working fine. but when It goes on big screen the effect takes place before the element come to view. What I want is effect takes place when element comes to view or when element come to half of the screen

Comment: No it works even in big screen. after running the code snippet you have a  `Full page` link on the right . click on it to check it in the full screen mode

Comment: Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yf062n7z/). it works

Comment: Did this fix your issue?

Comment: sorry I was trying to resolve... It didn't solve...  let me show you screenshot    `https://postimg.org/image/5fom31iml/` It adds class `wpb_start_animation` when the scroll is on top of the page and when i reach that section it removes the class :(

Comment: I think you have an inner scrolling(I mean some parent or grand parent of this div or root div with `position:fixed`) div if so, then use `$('div.yourscollerclass')` wherever I used `$(window)`

Comment: If you have any other scrolling element other than the body see my **Update**

Comment: didnt u try the update?

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will be useful.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
   .wpb_animate_when_almost_visible {
     height:200px;
     width:200px;
     background-color:red;
   }
  .wpb_start_animation{
    height:200px;
    width:900px;
    background-color:blue;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var scrollOffset = 200;
   $(window).scroll(function() {
    $('.wpb_animate_when_almost_visible').each(function() {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() - scrollOffset > $(this).position().top) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('wpb_start_animation')){
          $(this).removeClass('wpb_start_animation');
        }
        else {
          $(this).addClass('wpb_start_animation');
        }
      }
    });
 });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <div class="wpb_animate_when_almost_visible" data-scroll-to="100"></div>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <div class="wpb_animate_when_almost_visible" data-scroll-to="200"></div>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes Thankyou Priya.  Now problem is each time i scroll it adds removes class.  I want it to stays as it till that element is in view